# Assembly x86 Variables

Tags: variables, assembly, x86

this is a pretty easy straight forward question i have.

Basically, lets say there is NodeA and NodeB. They both contain 3 double words.

- The first element of NodeA should be initialized to null, the second element should be initialized to 100 and the third element should be initialized to the address of the NodeB.
- The first element of NodeB should be initialized to address of NodeA, the second element should be initialized to 200 and the third element should be initialized to null

I did try and code this but i am unsure if im completely right, especially with the "third element should be initialized to the address of the NodeB" part

here's what i got.

```
NodeA DWORD 0,100,NodeB
NodeB DWORD NodeA, 200, 0
```

is this correct?

Comment: Which assembler? Different assemblers have different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mentioned your Assembler:
For NASM:

```
NodeA dd 0,100,NodeB
NodeB dd NodeA, 200, 0
```

For MASM:

```
NodeA dd 0,100, offset NodeB
NodeB dd offset NodeA, 200, 0
```

Answer (score -1):

your code will not work. You must do something like this..

```
section .data
NodeA dd 0,100,0
NodeB dd 0,200,0

section .text

MOV place at NodeA+8, adress of NodeB
MOV place at NodeB, adress of NodeA
```

But I don't know how to do that. sorry

EDIT: See the example of @gunner . Your code works

Comment: oh you're right. I got the link error's because I used "dw" instead of "dd" thx